# Adding linear trend lines using subsets of data to a time series graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing research on the pandemic on Net Sales figures of companies in different industries. For this I have a dataset containing Net Sales figures of companies of the different industries. Now I would like to create plots per industry on one graph with 1 line corresponding to the aggregated Net Sales per year (from 2010-2020), and the other being a trend line from 2010-2019 onto 2020 (so the expected Net Sales for 2020 taking the previous years into account). This way I have a visual aid to see whether 2020 has seen significantly worse numbers.
I have gotten the first graphs (aggregated Net Sales per year per industry) sorted using `dplyr` with:

```
library(ggplot); library(tidyverse)
Industries <- df %>%
      group_by(NAICS, Year) %>%
      summarize(Sales = mean(`Net Sales`))
    
Industry_Plot <- ggplot(data = Industries, aes(Year, Sales)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1)
```

Now for the second part, I need to know:

1. How to graph the trend line per industry for 2020, and
2. How can I combine these onto 1 graph.

I have included a 'dput()' sample of my dataset for one industry below (these are the aggregated Net Sales for one industry (NAICS):

```
Industries <- structure(list(NAICS = c(315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315), 
    Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), 
    Sales = c(1839.94, 2227.27, 2203.9, 2421.88, 2681.7, 2789.2, 2834.07, 2944.34, 3129.65, 3213.13, 2757.85)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    groups = structure(list(NAICS = 315, .rows = structure(list(1:11), 
    ptype = integer(0), 
    class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
    row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), 
    class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am at a total loss. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760898/adding-trend-lines-boxplots-by-group-in-ggplot2

Comment: @dww Note that OP wants to have two trendlines in the same graph: one for 2010-2020. and other for 2010-2019, so question is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760898/adding-trend-lines-boxplots-by-group-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use geom_smooth(method='lm'...) with subset argument, e.g:

```
ggplot(data = Industries, aes(Year, Sales)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1)  +
 geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y~x, color='red', se=FALSE) + 
 geom_smooth(data=subset(Industries, Year < 2020), method='lm', formula= y~x, color='green', se=FALSE)
```

[image]